# jQuery.ajax() works only with integers

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Everything works fine and dandy with integers/floats but when I enter a String into the textbox the data never gets recieved by the C# method `GetData` .

ASP CODE

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtBoxVersion" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:ImageButton id="iconVersionSave" class="iconSave" runat="server" imageUrl="Resources/iconSave.png" OnClientClick="asyncServerCall(document.getElementById('txtBoxVersion').value); return false;"></asp:ImageButton>
```

JQUERY

```
function asyncServerCall(userData) 
{
    jQuery.ajax(
    {
        url: 'SurveyUpload.aspx/GetData',
        type: "POST",
        data: "{\"userData\":" + userData + "}",           //Data to be sent to the server !!WARNING!! Field Name must match C# parameter name
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  //when sending data to the server
        dataType: "json",                                //The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.
        success:
            function (data) 
            {
                alert('Success');}
            }
    });
}
```

C#

```
[WebMethod()]
        public static Boolean GetData(String userData)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(userData); //DEBUGGING

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: I'm used to doing ajax with a java backend, so this might be naive. But is there a reason that your curly braces are in quotes? I think this means you will be sending the string "{"userData":something}" as opposed to a POST with the parameter userData set to something.

Comment: Can't give you a detailed response on that but I do know it doesn't work without the brackets enclosed in quotes... Maybe someone else can chime in on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data: "{\"userData\":" + userData + "}"
```

Should be:

```
data: "{\"userData\":'" + userData + "'}"
```